# Laravel 4 - Repopulating form for edit with multiple check boxes

Tags: php, mysql, forms, laravel, laravel-4

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to repopulate a form for edit that has check boxes in it. I think the most confusing part is because they are coming from a pivot table.

I have users, permissions, and users_permissions tables.

For a quick demonstration of what the tables look like, I ran this query and included a screen clip of the results.

```
return $userPermissions = User::with('permissions')->find($id);
```

[image: Output of users table with permissions]

In my form I just have two permissions check boxes for now until I get the concept working, then I will add a foreach loop and grab them all from the database, but now I have the following:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>
        {{ Form::hidden('permissions[4]', '0', ['class' => 'checkbox-inline']) }}
        {{ Form::checkbox('permissions[4]', '1', ['class' => 'checkbox-inline']) }}
        Manage Content
     </label>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
     <label>
         {{ Form::hidden('permissions[3]', '0', ['class' => 'checkbox-inline']) }}
         {{ Form::checkbox('permissions[3]', '1', ['class' => 'checkbox-inline']) }}
         Manage Users
     </label>
  </div>
```

I'm not sure if this is useful information, but when I first create the user, I create a permissions array to attach to the new user. Here is the code for that,

```
public function createUserPermissionsArray($input)
{
    $permissionsArray = [];
    $permissions = $input['permissions'];

    foreach ($permissions as $id => $value)
    {
        if ($value == 1)
        {
            array_push($permissionsArray, $id);
        }
    }
    $this->saveNewUserToDatabase($input, $permissionsArray);

}
```

I really need some direction here about how to solve this problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently worked on something similar, except I had groups with permissions assigned to them, which users were then assigned to. For example, for `GroupController::edit()` I had this code:

```
public function edit($id)
{
    if(!permitted('group.edit')) {
        return Redirect::route('user.dashboard');
    }

    $group = Group::find($id);
    $permissions = Permission::all();

    return View::make('admin.group.edit', [
        'group' => $group, 
        'permissions' => $permissions, 
        'assigned' => $group->permissions->lists('id')
    ]);
}
```

Then within the form partial for the view (`admin.group.partials.form`), I had the following code to handle permissions:

```
@foreach($permissions as $permission)
    <div class="row">
        @if(isset($assigned))
            {{ Form::checkbox(
                'permissions[' . $permission->ident .']', 
                $permission->id, 
                in_array($permission->id, $assigned)) 
            }}<label for="permissions">{{ $permission->ident }} - {{ $permission->description }}</label>
        @else
            {{ Form::checkbox(
                'permissions[' . $permission->ident .']', 
                $permission->id) 
            }}<label for="group">{{ $permission->ident }} - {{ $permission->description }}</label>
        @endif
    </div>
@endforeach
```

I've formatted it the best I can, so that it's easy to read. Basically I had a `create.blade.php` and `edit.blade.php` which both include the form partial, but each file handles the opening and closing of the form (model binding for edit, normal open for create), hence the if statement.

Unfortunately I couldn't find a better method to achieve this. I hope this helps you.

P.S: As a side note, I've actually written a tutorial about creating a robust and simple ACL with Laravel, I can link if you'd like.

Comment: If you look in the first bit of code, you'll see it's data that I pass in `'assigned' => $group->permissions->lists('id')`, that basically just creates a single array containing all of the ids of the permissions assigned with the group.

Comment: Thanks a ton, much appreciated. Yeah I figured it the `$assigned` variable, thanks again.

Comment: No problem at all, glad I could help. The ACL tutorial is http://ollieread.com/blog/2014/03/18/a-simplified-laravel-acl/ if you wanted to take a look